# ANDROID - Can't go to a page

Tags: android, android-activity

**MAINMENU.CLASS**

```
 public class MainMenu extends Activity {
    ImageButton playButton;
    ImageButton soundButton;
    SoundPlayers soundPlayers;
    MediaPlayer firstMenusMusic;
    MediaPlayer arenaMusic;
    MediaPlayer buttonSound;
    boolean now_sound;
    OthersIO othersIO;
    //MediaPlayer firstMenusMusic;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);
        playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        soundButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sfx_sound);
        playButtonEvent();
    }

    private void playButtonEvent() {
        playButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainMenu.this, UserConfig.class);

                MainMenu.this.finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }       
}
```

**USERCONFIG.CLASS**

```
   public class UserConfig extends Activity {
    ImageButton userConfigBack;
    ImageButton userConfigOK;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.user_config);
         ....
    }

    public void chooseCharacter() {
        ....
    }

    public void back() {
        userConfigBack.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = new Intent(UserConfig.this, MainMenu.class);
                UserConfig.this.finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void OK() {
        userConfigOK.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(UserConfig.this, EnemyConfig1.class);
                UserConfig.this.finish();
                createPlayerData();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    public void createPlayerData() {
        ....
    }


}
```

This is the Android Manifest :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ulartangga"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.ulartangga.MainMenu"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <activity 
            android:name=".UserConfig" 
            android:parentActivityName=".MainMenu" >
           <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainMenu" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EnemyConfig1" 
            android:parentActivityName=".UserConfig"
            >
           <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".UserConfig" />      
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EnemyConfig2" 
            android:parentActivityName=".EnemyConfig1"
            >
           <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".EnemyConfig1" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Arena" 
            android:parentActivityName=".EnemyConfig1"
            >
           <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".EnemyConfig1" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My problem is...
when I click play button on view from mainmenu.class. I can go to another page(go to view from userconfig.class). but when I click OK button in view from userconfig.class, I can't go to another page.

Comment: why people give minus point

Comment: If you hover over the downvote button you'll notice the text "This question shows no research effort; it is unclear or not useful". I don't find the question particulary clear, but my knowledge about Android is non-existant, so I can't tell if that's because I just don't have the knowledge to understand the question or if the question is actually unclear. I can recommend reading through [this help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and looking if there is something you might be able to improve.

Comment: the downvoter doesn't understand this question. he didn't know that this question is understandable. Thanks, for your tips. That is good thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `USERCONFIG.CLASS` change it to

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.user_config);
         OK();
         back();
    }
```

Comment: I have called OK and back methods but still don't work

Comment: can you try to add `Log.i("xxx", "before onclick");` inside the `public void onClick(View arg0)` to see if the onclick method is really being called.

Answer (score 0):

call `UserConfig.this.finish();` after `startActivity()`